# How do I provide the shared library path for LLVM lld?

Tags: c++, linker, gnu, lld

I am trying to use LLVM lld linker instead of the GNU ld linker that I was previously using.

```
ld --version
```

> LLD 8.0.0 (compatible with GNU linkers)

I have some shared libraries placed in `/usr/local/lib`. I had the path set in `ld.so.conf` for the GNU ld linker to find the libraries. However, lld ignores `ld.so.conf`. I also tried to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

> /usr/local/lib

But lld seems to ignore that as well. How can I add `/usr/local/lib` to the lld linker search path?

Answer (score -1):

> How can I add /usr/local/lib to the lld linker search path?

This should work:

```
ld -L /usr/local/lib ...
```

> Had the path set in ld.so.conf for the GNU ld linker to find the libraries.

The GNU ld doesn't care about `ld.so.conf` *at all* (only `ld-linux` looks there), but GNU ld does look in `/usr/local/lib` by default.